# Route is redirecting before calling the controller method

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I am using Laravel 5.5.40 along with the Zizaco\Entrust Pacakge

In my `routes/web.php` file i have the following route setup.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'order'], function() {
    Route::get('', 'OrderController@getMe');
});
```

It is supposed to call the `getMe()` method inside the `OrderController.php` but it instead redirects to **www.mydomain.co.uk/home**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class OrderController extends Controller
{    
    public function getMe() {
        return "You got me!";
    }
}
```

As a test, I added a `__construct` function to the `OrderController.php` to see if the class was even been loaded.

```
public function __construct() {
    dd("Testing");
}
```

When accessing **www.mydomain.co.uk/order** i now get

```
"Testing"
```

I can't seem to work out why it is not running the `getMe()` method. Could anyone possibly shine some light on this please?

I have also tried changing the route to use `ClientController@list` which works fine.

Contents of `ClientController.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Client;

class ClientController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct() {
        //
    }

    // Display all the clients
    public function list() {
        $tabContent = [
            'display_type' => 'list',
            'data' => Client::orderBy('name', 'asc')->get(),
            'view_params' => [
                'columns' => [
                    'name' => 'Client Name',
                    'address_line_1' => 'Address Line 1',
                    'town' => 'Town',
                    'county' => 'County',
                    'post_code' => 'Post Code'
                ],
                'links' => 'client',
                'controls' => True
            ]
        ];
        return view('tables.list', ['data' => $tabContent]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has become apparent that if the controller does not have the constructor function in it, it will automatically redirect to the root of the URI with no error.

```
public function __construct() {
    //
}
```